# Cannot set property 'address' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I try to handle select dropdown list onchange event from function in file but I get exception. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Region"></label>
    <select id="Select" name="Region" asp-items="@Model.Region" class="form-control" onchange="site.action.address.loadTown()">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Избери област</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Region" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<script src="~/files/js/Core/site.action.address.js"></script>
```

In the file it is like:

```
(function (site, $, undefined) {
    site.action.address = {};
    let me = site.action.address;
    me.loadTown = function () {
        let test = "test";console.log(test);
    };
})(window.site= window.site|| {}, jQuery);
```

Comment: `undefined` is a reserved keyword, why have you declared a function argument with that name (which you then do not even use in your function body)? Also, given what you push into your function as `site`, why would even the first line of the function be guaranteed to succeed? If the fallback `{}` gets used, `site.action` won't exist because you did not provide a safe fallback object. You want `if (!site) return` or something as first line, at the least.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Just want to point to out that `undefined` is NOT a reserved keyword in javascript. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)

Comment: Thanks for that correction. "`undefined` is an existing primitive value in JavaScript, why have you declared a function argument with that name?".

Comment: I think the problem here is that the action is not yet defined, and will cause address property to be undefined